# Java Serial connection and file problem (Arduino and Java)

Tags: java, arduino, arduino-uno

I have an arduino uno connected to my PC, and I'm trying to use a java program that creates a gui so I an connect to the Serial Port and store all the data in a file that would be named with today's date.

but when I use it to try and connect to the serial port I get a lot of errors.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class FluidDynamicSerial implements ActionListener {

    //main frame
    JFrame window;

    //create class members for buttons/check-box and drop-down
    JComboBox<String> portList;
    JButton connectButton;
    JCheckBox multFilesDay;

    //variables for files
    boolean nameWithTime = false;
    String name;

    //warning message
    String msg = "This file already exists. By default all files are named with today's date, if you wish to fix this problem either rename the file in the current diretory or click the multiple files in one day chekbox";

    //serial port var
    SerialPort port;


    //file vars
    File file;
    FileWriter writeFile;
    BufferedWriter buffWriteFile;

    //Date var
    Date date;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FluidDynamicSerial();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public FluidDynamicSerial() {
        //create window
        window = new JFrame();
        window.setTitle("Save Sensor Readings");
        window.setSize(300, 150);
        window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //create drop-down and button to connect to serial port
        portList = new JComboBox<String>();
        connectButton = new JButton("Connect");

        //create Top Panel to place drop-down & button
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.add(portList);
        topPanel.add(connectButton);
        window.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        //create middle panel with hekBox to have multiple files in one day
        multFilesDay = new JCheckBox("Multiple Files in one day");
        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.add(multFilesDay);
        window.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //place serial port options in drop-down
        SerialPort[] portOptions = SerialPort.getCommPorts();
        for(int i = 0; i < portOptions.length; i++) {
            portList.addItem(portOptions[i].getSystemPortName());
        }

        //file code
        date = new Date();
        String month = new Integer(date.getMonth()+1).toString();
        String yr = new Integer(date.getYear()+1900).toString();

        if(nameWithTime == true) {
            name = month + "-" + date.getDate() + "-" + yr + "_" + date.getHours() + "_" + date.getMinutes() + ".txt";
        } else {
            name = month + "-" + date.getDate() + "-" + yr + ".txt";
        }

        file = new File(name);



        window.setVisible(true);

        connectButton.addActionListener(this);
        multFilesDay.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        Object control = event.getSource();

        if(control == connectButton) {
            if(connectButton.getText().equals("Connect")) {
                port = SerialPort.getCommPort(portList.getSelectedItem().toString());
                port.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_SCANNER, 0, 0);
                if(port.openPort()) {
                    connectButton.setText("Disconnect");
                    portList.setEnabled(false);
                }
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(port.getInputStream());
                while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
                    if(file.exists()) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(window,
                                msg,
                                "File Dupliation Error",
                                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        scan.close();
                    } else {
                        try {
                            writeFile = new FileWriter(file);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        buffWriteFile = new BufferedWriter(writeFile);
                        String line = scan.nextLine();
                        try {
                            buffWriteFile.append(date.toString() + " " + line + " " + "\n");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                scan.close();
                try {
                    buffWriteFile.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                port.closePort();
                portList.setEnabled(true);
                connectButton.setText("Connect");
            }
        } else if(control == multFilesDay) {
            if(multFilesDay.isEnabled()) {
                nameWithTime = true;
            } else if(multFilesDay.isEnabled() == false) {
                nameWithTime = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the program to create a text file whose name would be today's date and it would have all my data from the serial port (voltage readings) in it.

Comment: Can you update the question with the errors you faced ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rearranged some of my code and modified it and it works now, thanks to anyone who tried to help